# Div nested inside another div isn't visible

Tags: html, css

I created a modal, but a child `div` inside the modal isn't showing up and I can't figure out why.

For clarity, it's the `.divs1` div in the example below that isn't visible.

```css
.ssmodal {
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*height: 100%;*/
  /*margin: auto;*/
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  background-color: #fefefe; /* Fallback color */
  /*background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: 'Mukta';
  border:2px solid red;
}
.divz1 {
    z-index: -1;
  border:2px solid blue;
}
P {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal" class="ssmodal">
    <div id="divs1" class="divz1">
        <p>TESTINGGGGGGG</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ssmodal` div has `display:none` property

Comment: remove `display: none;` from `.ssmodal {}`

Comment: You'll want to get familiar with your browser's document inspector. That would've been an easy catch for you.

Comment: Why "z-index: -1;" value for .divz1?

Comment: @Hanif i wanted to add some code on top of it saw it will stay behind it

Answer (score 2):

Parent div `ssmodal` has the property `display:none`. This will hide any child elements of the parent div.

Removing the property should show the child div.

Comment: check my question again, I added something to it

Comment: the div is showing up in chrome - [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hscfpa). Which is your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Since your div that should be shown, is inside the parent div tag, and as you have added the property `display:none;` , it won't show anything inside that div. Hence try changing the `display: none;`

Comment: check my question again, I added something to it.

Comment: Yep, it's correct. Are you able to get the result? If not try using inspect elements from the browser and play with it, try changing the values and try to understand what is happening. @KacperKwapisz

Comment: If your problem was a visibility problem I can assure that your inner div is showed with your last source code (in the question I mean)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you put the z-index value -1 to class **.divz1**, I think that's the main issue here.

As the css right now the class **.divz1** is floating one layer down, if you change the value greater than 1, surely it will fix your issue.